# Upper and lower bound interpretation

Tags: drake

How is this sequence of outputs possible?

For the following code block:

```
 for cons in prog.GetAllConstraints():
        if not prog.CheckSatisfiedAtInitialGuess(cons):
            print("ln470 constraint failed")
            print(prog.CheckSatisfiedAtInitialGuess(cons))
            print(cons.evaluator().get_description())
            print(cons.evaluator().Eval(prog.initial_guess()))
            print(cons.evaluator().upper_bound())
            print(cons.evaluator().lower_bound())
```

I get this print out:

```
ln470 constraint failed
False
abs value geq constraint
[52.4021 50.1494 22.4349]
[inf inf inf]
[3.3518 0.     0.    ]
```

The constraint is within the upper and lower bound. So why is it returning CheckSatisfied == false?

Comment: What is the class type of of `cons.evaluator()`?  If its not a Drake class, please also provide that class's source code.

Comment: my guess is that the variables in the constraint evaluator are not exactly `prog.initial_guess()`.  `prog.initial_guess()` will return all of the variables in the program, but Eval uses the variables that are bound with the constraint.

Try using [`prog.EvalBindingAtInitialGuess`](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1solvers_1_1_mathematical_program.html#a0eb46a0ff11d6f6d22d69d9c16bfce94) instead?